# php script can not connect to java virtual machine ip address?

Tags: java, php, curl, file-get-contents, fsockopen

I have php script that tries to access a virtual machine using a give IP address. I have tried many codes like: fsockopen, socket_connect, file_get_contents, curl, fsockopen. they all fail. the problem is its not a real ip address it virtual so it can't connect.

Is there a way to connect to this? find the real domain? find the real IP? connect to the java ?
any help would be nice.